# dynamically adding elements into object from php array

Tags: javascript

```
    var mydata0 = null;
    $.post('php/ProductionChange.php', function(data) { // This is Where 
    I use an AJAX call into a php file.

      mydata0=data; // This takes the array from the call and puts it 
      //into
     //a variable 
      var pa = JSON.parse(mydata0);             
       var temp = {};


     for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {

    var job=pa[i][0];
    var shipdate = pa[i][1];
    var status = pa[i][2];
    var name = pa[i][3];
    var EnclLoc = pa[i][13];
    var Enclsize = pa[i][14];
    var BackPanLoc = pa[i][15];
    var percentCom = pa[i][16];
    var isVis = pa[i][17];
    var png = pa[i][18];
    var WorkC = pa[i][20];
    temp={'bayData': job, shipdate, name, EnclLoc, Enclsize, BackPanLoc, 
    percentCom, isVis, png, WorkC};

    isVacant1.push(temp);
```

*So I am trying to accomplish is take the object coming out of the pa array***

`(0: Array[21] 1: Array[21] 2: Array[21] 3: Array[21] 4: Array[21] 5: Array[21])`

which has 6 different arrays inside of it accounting to a total of 816 items. My temp variables successfully grabs onto all the items that I want and isVacant1 successfully gets all of the 6 push inside of it, resulting in isVacant being an array of 6 objects.

However the breaks down once the for loop is over and the error message I am getting is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined** with a red
>   x next to the first line of my code once the for loop starts **(var
>   job=...)

Please tell me the steps into solving this issue. Thank you for all the help.*

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i <= pa.length; i++) {
```

You are iterating for length of the data array, but accessing pa.  pa is not necessarily the same length as the array called "data".

Comment: lol I literally caught that error as soon as I submitted this question. I am glad for the quick responses. Thanks bud.